# Партицирование по дате mysql

Tags: mysql, partition

Всем привет! Есть непонятки с партицированием таблицы. Имеется таблица 'items'. 18 млн записей:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `log_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `res_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `link` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `title` text NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `n_date` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `nd_date` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `s_date` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `not_date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `link_2` (`link`),
  KEY `log_id` (`log_id`),
  KEY `res_id` (`res_id`),
  KEY `now_date` (`not_date`),
  KEY `sql_index` (`res_id`,`id`,`not_date`)
) ENGINE=Aria  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 PAGE_CHECKSUM=0 AUTO_INCREMENT=18382133 ;
```

Хочу осуществить партицирование данной таблицы по дате. В качестве тестирования создал маленькую копию этой таблицы, где поле 'not_date' включил в состав имеющихся первичных и уникальных ключей.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `part_items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `log_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `res_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `link` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `title` text NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `n_date` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `nd_date` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `s_date` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `not_date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`not_date`,`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `link_2` (`not_date`,`link`),
  KEY `log_id` (`log_id`),
  KEY `res_id` (`res_id`),
  KEY `now_date` (`not_date`),
  KEY `sql_index` (`res_id`,`id`,`not_date`)
) ENGINE=Aria  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 PAGE_CHECKSUM=0
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE ( TO_DAYS(not_date))
(PARTITION p_1 VALUES LESS THAN (735963) ENGINE = Aria,
 PARTITION p_2 VALUES LESS THAN (736694) ENGINE = Aria) */ AUTO_INCREMENT=18414661 ;
```

После чего выполнил запрос партицирования:

```
alter table `part_items` PARTITION BY RANGE( TO_DAYS(not_date) ) (
PARTITION p_1 VALUES LESS THAN( TO_DAYS('2014-12-31') ),
PARTITION p_2 VALUES LESS THAN( TO_DAYS('2016-12-31') )
);
```

В итоге выполняю запрос, который по логике должен обратиться только в партицию p_1. Explain показывает все верно. Тогда выполняю другой запрос, который по логике должен осуществлять поиск только в p_2. Но тут почему то explain показывает, что поиск проводился в обоих партициях. Что я сделал не так? Заранее спасибо!
Вот первый и второй запросы:

```
explain partitions SELECT * FROM `part_items` where content like '%k%' and not_date < '2014-05-12'

explain partitions SELECT * FROM `part_items` where content like '%k%' and not_date > '2015-01-01'
```

Comment: Гм... а зачем партиционирование делается по значению функции, а не по значению собственно поля? У Вас же не TIMESTAMP...

Comment: Партиционирование принимает только интовые значения, насколько я знаю

Comment: См. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-range.html , последний пример статьи.

Comment: Хорошо, но это не решает мою проблему

Comment: Ну не понимает он, может быть. В условиях партиционирования указано LESS THEN - вот он и учитывает, когда в условии "меньше". И не учитывает, когда "больше". И боюсь, что и в варианте `and NOT(not_date < '2015-01-01')` он тоже не поймёт, что можно использовать только вторую партицию...

Comment: Очень подробно партицирование данных на примере БД Mysql (MariaDB) рассмотрен в статье [Как обрабатывать статистику за длительный период](https://onlinebd.ru/blog/kak-obrabatyvat-statistiku-za-dlitelnyi-period)
рекомендую

Answer (score 1):

запрос не использует конкретную партицию поскольку вы использовали функцию, а вам нужно использовать данные столбца:

```
ALTER TABLE `part_items` 
 PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS(not_date) PARTITIONS 3(
    PARTITION   p_1  VALUES LESS THAN ( '2014-12-31' ),
    PARTITION   p_2  VALUES LESS THAN ( '2016-12-31' ),
    PARTITION   p_3  VALUES LESS THAN (   MAXVALUE   )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

А в обратном порядке пробовал? Т. е.

```
explain partitions 
SELECT * FROM `part_items` 
where not_date > '2015-01-01' 
and content like '%k%'
```

Чтобы он сперва выделил раздел, а затем проверил.